# Why is a mixed model a non-linear statistical model?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model

I was wondering if anyone could elaborate more on this statement which I came across whilst reading a book on non-linear mixed effects model. I know that you can have linear, generalised linear and non-linear  mixed effect models.

The book says

> mixed models are non-linear statistical models, due mainly to the presence of variance parameters.

How do I explain this to someone who understands very little statistics?

For instance, how can a linear mixed effect model be non-linear?

Comment: Can you write down how they're specified mathematically? There's definitely some ambiguity about what a linear model is and about what a mixed effect model is.

Comment: @CloseToC, thanks for your reply. There's no other mathematical definition given with that statement. The only other thing attributed to this non-linearity is the presence of variance parameters. This language is just very misleading and I really don't know what that means. I've edited my post to include this statement.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hopefully the amount of notation suppressed and corners cut in what follows still leaves something intelligible:

**On what 'mixed' means**. Imagine somewhere at the heart of the model we have a line looking something like this.

$$\eta = \beta_0 +  \beta_1 x_1 + ... +  \beta_p x_p$$

Where the $x_k$ are our covariates. Focus on the coefficients, the $\beta_k$. We could either: think of these as fixed numbers (fixed effects) or as random numbers (random effects).

Why might we want to think of a $\beta_k$ as random? For example, imagine a situation where each person gets their own intercept term $\beta_0$. This might represent them being naturally healthier, faster, smarter or whatever. We could then model what effect a drug / treatment had *on top of* their individual natural level.  We might want to think of the effect of the drug or treatment though as being fixed and bumping $\eta$ up or down by the same amount for every individual.

Hence the term mixed effects where some are random (e.g., person's natural level) and some are fixed (e.g., effect of treatment).

**On linear and non-linear**.

The 'linear' in generalised linear models refers to the equation for $\eta$ above.

If $\mu$ is the mean of the variable we are modelling then we can do non-linear things with $\eta$ like:

$$\mu = \frac{1}{1+e^{-\eta}}$$

Which is involved in logistic regression. Or

$$\mu = e^{\eta}$$

As in models for count data.

This is where having random effects in $\eta$ can cause some real bumps. Suppose we have a prior distribution for $\beta_0\sim\mathcal N(0,g)$. Then for example with logistic data:

$$E[Y]=E[E[Y|\beta_0]]=\int \frac{1}{1+e^{-\eta}} (2\pi)^{-1/2}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\beta_0^2} d \beta_0$$

Which is pretty hairy, despite the fact that $\beta_0$ was added *as a linear term* to $\eta$. Think about the distribution of $\beta_0$ which is symmetric, but taking $\exp()$ of it is not.

However if we model $\mu=\eta$ things work out nice and the random terms disappear from the mean upon marginalisation. They don't, however, disappear from the variance.

Suppose for some observation $i$, with a random intercept (which is independent of the error term $\varepsilon_i \sim\mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)$):

$$Y_i|\beta_0 = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \varepsilon_i$$

Then

$$E[Y_i]=E[E[Y_i|\beta_0]]=E[\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1]=\beta_1 x_1$$

But

$${\rm Var}(Y_i)={\rm Var}(\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \varepsilon_i) = {\rm Var}(\beta_0) + {\rm Var}( \varepsilon_i) = g + \sigma^2$$

So the 'variance parameters' still show up.

Answer (score 3):

And, here's a "street" version of the above:
a) what is a linear model? It's one which can be expressed in the form of sums and scalar products of the inputs (y = ax + b at the simplest).  If "a" is a function of some other factor ("z" not "x") perhaps a random function, A(z), then we have y = A(z)x + b which is no longer a linear model.

b) what is a "mixed-model?" One which has linear parts and non-linear parts:  y = ax + A(Z)x + b

Comment: @A Friend, thanks for that post-very short but quite precise and easy to understand. So I guess its the function A(Z) that makes it non-linear. Quite different from the definition of linear/non-linear in differential equations.